# Incorrect 404 for pages when using permalink, a static front page, and posts page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, theme-roots

I am having an issue with my permalink setup, which I think has to do with my setup, rewrite rules, and more.

Under Settings->Reading, we have a static Front Page set as well as a Posts page (Home and News, respectively). Under Settings->Permalinks, I have a custom one set up as `/news/%postname%/`.

Basically, I want my url to look like this for an article: `http://www.company.com/news/a-news-article/`. I want `http://www.company.com/news/` to take me to my articles.

As of right now, this is 90% there. What I noticed is that if I go to `http://www.company.com/news/not-a-post/`, where `not-a-post` is not created, I get a 404. But, if I go to `http://www.company.com/asdf`, I would expect a 404. Instead, it loads the front page (the static front page).

For our setup, we are using the roots theme as a base, and not using htaccess, everything is in the httpd.conf. Our rewrite rules look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/thetheme/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/thetheme/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/thetheme/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/font/(.*) /wp-content/themes/thetheme/font/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

When I enabled logging, it says that it sent it to index.php, which should be right. But why doesn't index.php handle this 404 correctly?

If I use the 'Day and Name' option from permalinks, everything looks and works right. It also appears that if I use `/news/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`, it works as it should too. Why won't it work with just `/news/%postname%/`?